# difference between _Fract , _Sat and _Accum in GCC and why to use Fixed-point types?

Tags: c, gcc, decimal

I was reading GCC documentation on Fixed-point types [from this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed-Point.html#Fixed-Point)  , but it seems GCC is not Elaborating on so many things which left me with many questions in my head

1. first of all they, said

> The fixed-point types are short _Fract, _Fract, long _Fract, long long _Fract, unsigned short _Fract, unsigned _Fract, unsigned long _Fract, unsigned long long _Fract, _Sat short _Fract, _Sat _Fract, _Sat long _Fract, _Sat long long _Fract, _Sat unsigned short _Fract, _Sat unsigned _Fract, _Sat unsigned long _Fract, _Sat unsigned long long _Fract, short _Accum, _Accum, long _Accum, long long _Accum, unsigned short _Accum, unsigned _Accum, unsigned long _Accum, unsigned long long _Accum, _Sat short _Accum, _Sat _Accum, _Sat long _Accum, _Sat long long _Accum, _Sat unsigned short _Accum, _Sat unsigned _Accum, _Sat unsigned long _Accum, _Sat unsigned long long _Accum.

so what are the differences between

- _Fract
- _Sat
- _Accum

since the fixed point types are just combination between primitive data type and the above 3 key works ,so what is the difference when I write `short _Fract x;` or `short _Accum x;` ? and what does keyword **_Sat** add to the definition of the variable ? like what is the difference between `_Sat _Fract x;` and `_Sat _Accum x;` ? as GCC didn't state anything about this thing ,

also they said:

> Not all targets support fixed-point types.

so I couldn't test anything from the above types on my host machines as it gives me error stating that **fixed-point types not supported for this target**

2. I have read about **Decimal** , **float** and **Fixed-Point** types

all of the above are just different representations of decimal with fraction numbers , from my understand they are just like:

- Decimal representation gives lower accuracy but higher range with big numbers , most 2 used standards are binary integer decimal (BID) and densely packed decimal (DPD)
- float and doubles gives higher accuracy than Decimal when talking about big numbers but lower range ,they follow IEEE 754 standard
- Fixed-Point types have the lowest range but they are the most accurate one

please correct me if I am wrong on the above 3 lines , so my question is as follow , in the narrow range of small numbers like when we are talking about Fixed-Point types , they provide high accuracy but also Decimals can be used instead of them in that small range and Decimals will provide same accuracy as nearly as Fixed-Point types , Decimals only lacks accuracy when numbers become big , so why we use Fixed-Point types ? as it will give us only small range of numbers and decimal can replace it in terms of accuracy in that small range of numbers.

Comment: `how to use _Fract , _Sat and _Accum in GCC` Is a broad question. As they were intended to use, like any other type.

Comment: @KamilCuk , yeah ok , but what is the difference between them ? that is what i really meant by my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1169.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format) .

> what is the difference when I write short _Fract x; or short _Accum x; ?

`short _Fract` would be a variable 1 sign bit and 15 fraction bits, `short _Accum` would be a variable with 1 sign bit, 8 integer bits and 7 fraction bits. (Most commonly)

Different compilers have different sizes: https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-C4E60FF5-3DAB-44F1-BA61-4BD962D8F469-en-US-1/index.html?GUID-8856FDD7-C356-499B-9B39-8F7304854058 . I saw such a list for GCC of all fixed-point types, but I can't find it.

> what is the difference between them ?

The difference is in the representation, which translates into a different range and resolution of representable values. They have different count of integer and fraction bits.

> what does keyword _Sat add to the definition of the variable ?

`_Sat` comes from *saturating fixed-point type*. When you do `UINT_MAX + 1` it becomes 0, because it wraps around. In pseudocode, like `(_Sat UINT_MAX) + 1` would be equal to `UINT_MAX`. It "saturates", not wraps around.

> fixed-point types not supported for this target

So use a different target. For example, the following program:

```
#include <stdfix.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    _Fract unsigned a = UFRACT_MAX;
    _Fract unsigned b = a + 0.1;
    _Sat _Fract unsigned c = UFRACT_MAX;
    _Sat _Fract unsigned d = c + 0.1;
    printf("a=%f a+0.1=%f\n", (float)a, (float)b);  // b "wrapped around"
    printf("c=%f c+0.1=%f\n", (float)c, (float)d);  // d is "capped to max"
}
```

Can be executed like the following:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -ufloat_print --specs=rdimon.specs 1.c && qemu-arm ./a.out 
a=0.999985 a+0.1=0.099976
c=0.999985 c+0.1=0.999985
```

> why we use Fixed-Point types ?

Speed. Calculating `float * float` is super hard and slow. Calculating `int * int` is superfast. Calculating `fixed-point * fixed-point` is exactly as fast as `int * int`.

Comment: You might want to correct the `printf()`. ;-)

Comment: I mean, you have two `"%d"` but only one argument.